# Minimun privileges for CSI sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, privileges, linux-capabilities, security-context, csi

I'm building my own CSI driver with CSI standards and I'm wondering about the Security Context to be set for the CSI sidecar containers.

I'm going to use:

- Node Driver Registrar
- CSI provisioner
- CSI attacher
- CSI liveness probe.

Some of them need to run as root and I'm wondering about the configuration in the Security Context to assign them the minimum Linux capabilities and to be sure that root capabilities are provided for the minimum time.

Am I forced to set the security context as follows? Is there any way to restrict it furthermore?

```
securityContext:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  privileged: false
  runAsNonRoot: true
  capabilities:
    drop:
    - all
    add:
    - SYS_ADMIN
```

Thanks in advance,
Antonio

Comment: Welcome to the community! Are you following any tutorial or documentation? I'm referring to the manifest snippet you added

Comment: Hi moonkotte,
I'm following the Security Context's field description:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#securitycontext-v1-core
Thanks!
Antonio

Comment: Will this work in RHCOS setup as well?

Comment: I tried this for the cert-manager csi driver and got an error from Kubernetes that says:`helm.go:84: [debug] cannot patch "cert-manager-csi-driver" with kind DaemonSet: DaemonSet.apps "cert-manager-csi-driver" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts.mountPropagation: Forbidden: Bidirectional mount propagation is available only to privileged containers` even with `allowPrivilegeEscalation: true` so I think now we need to have even `privileged: true` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Based on research about kubernetes and linux capabilities, that looks you've already found the least possible privileges.

Your example contains minimum needed capability - `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` which is used primarily for `mounting` and `unmounting` filesystems.

In more details `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is used for:

- Perform a range of system administration operations including: quotactl(2), mount(2), umount(2), pivot_root(2), swapon(2), swapoff(2), sethostname(2),
  and setdomainname(2);
- use ioprio_set(2) to assign IOPRIO_CLASS_RT and (before Linux 2.6.25) IOPRIO_CLASS_IDLE I/O scheduling classes;
- exceed /proc/sys/fs/file-max, the system-wide limit on
  the number of open files, in system calls that open
  files (e.g., accept(2), execve(2), open(2), pipe(2));
- call setns(2) (requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN in the target
  namespace);
- employ the TIOCSTI ioctl(2) to insert characters into
  the input queue of a terminal other than the caller's
  controlling terminal;
- employ the obsolete nfsservctl(2) system call;
- employ the obsolete bdflush(2) system call;
- perform various privileged block-device ioctl(2)
  operations;
- perform various privileged filesystem ioctl(2) operations;
- perform privileged ioctl(2) operations on the /dev/random device (see random(4));
- perform administrative operations on many device drivers;

Source - [capabilities(7) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

---

Also there is a very good article with many details about docker images and security aspects can be found here - [Towards unprivileged container builds](https://kinvolk.io/blog/2018/04/towards-unprivileged-container-builds/)

One more article explains `linux capabilities` and its appliance with examples may be helpful - [HackTricks - Linux Capabilities](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/linux-unix/privilege-escalation/linux-capabilities)